# PayPal Express Checkout is not setup on this account

Tags: php, paypal, payflowpro, payflowlink

I am wondering why am I getting this error when redirecting my acquired SECURETOKEN and SECURETOKENID to https://payflowlink.paypal.com.

According to this [source](https://www.e-junkie.com/wiki/trouble-paypal-advanced-test-mode), it happens if transaction mode is set to test, so I did set it to LIVE.

[image]

My services are also in live, so far that what I saw from searching.

[image]

and the account I used has this role: "API_FULL_TRANSACTIONS".

I acquire my Securetoken by sending this request to:

```
https://payflowpro.paypal.comTRXTYPE=S&TENDER=P&ACTION=S&PARTNER=PayPalCA&VENDOR=vendor&USER=user&PWD=password&AMT=16.95&CURRENCY=CAD&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=c326093c-2f40-4555-ac9f-213aa918dfdf&CANCELURL=https://www.cancelurl.com/cart/checkoutprocess/cancel&RETURNURL=https://www.returnurl.com/cart/checkoutprocess_rsp&ORDERDESC=Business Subscription
```

and response:

```
SECURETOKEN=securetokenvalue&SECURETOKENID=securetokenidvalue&RESPMSG=Approved
```

and then redirect it to

```
https://payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKENID=securetokenidvalue&SECURETOKEN=securetokenvalue
```

The result will be:

[image]

Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/secure-token/

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when Express Checkout is not set up on that particular Payflow merchant ID you are using (for the particular mode you are doing transactions in, be it TEST or LIVE)

Anyone still getting this error and unable to resolve it by switching to a different mode would need to contact PayPal or Payflow merchant support to ask them to set EC up, since no one else can do it for you.